# Spring, Hibernate, Delete record older than 5 Min

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a table called 'otp', I need to delete records that is older than a certain period, let say 5 minutes for now.
I use Spring Framework with hibernate with MySql. I tried all possible ways, writing a '@Query' in the DTO interface, trying the Spring Data query way, I even tried to do a 'Select' on the records. When running in the code it does not select any records nor does it delete any records older than the period asked for. When I copy the 'Query" statement into the MySQL workbench it do work, I only need to put the DB name in front of the table name to get it to work. Below is snippets of the code. I removed the "@Query" statement and kept the Spring Data query.

Thank you in advance for your help.

The Entity or model.
'

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "otp")
public class Otp {
    @Id
    @Column(name="phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(name="otp")
    private String otp;
    @Column(name="createdOn", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createdOn;
}
```

`

Code that must delete the rows.

```
'

@Repository
public interface OTPdto extends CrudRepository<Otp, String> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void deleteByCreatedOnLessThan(Object now);

}
```

'

Code that build the date for the query.

'

```
Date now = Date.from(Instant.now());
                    Object param = new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime());
                    otPdto.deleteByCreatedOnLessThan(param);
```

'

Comment: Just curious. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell by provided info, but maybe I can help.
First of all, I would make sure that CreatedOn column gets filled in with correct information. Also I would try something like `deleteByCreatedOnBefore(java.sql.Timestamp time)` instead of `deleteByCreatedOnLessThan(Object now)`. java.sql.Timestamp is not raw timestamp value, so maybe comparasing "LessThan" doesn't work well with that.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the suggestion, unfortunately not working. Here is the data in the table for the timestamp '2021-02-10 11:42:47'

Comment: @BKruger Check the passing date and database dates are in the same timezone. else it will not delete desired record other wise above given code is correct.

Comment: bharatpatel  - I have changed the type in the sql script from timestamp to DateTime for the createdOn column,  I also change the variable form TimeStamp to use java.util.Date - @Column(name="createdOn", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdOn = new Date(); Not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

I will go another route and just clear the otp field. Seems I need to keep the phone number in the Db. Will use the phone number in future to remove the record.

Comment: The issue was that the dto object was still null at this stage even though I used Autowired.